# Self contained exposition of second order Fuchsian ODEs

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, monodromy

I am teaching a graduate course in Complex Analysis.  I would like students to give an oral presentation at the end of the term on a topic which we did not cover in the lecture.  So I am putting together a list of textbook chapters and expository papers on various topics.

One topic which I think is very nice, and uses many of the tools we will cover in the course, is the theory of second order Fuchsian ODEs.  However, I have been unable to find an exposition of this topic which is "self contained" in the sense that it is relatively short (10 to 15 pages) and assumes only the background of a one semester complex analysis course (basically they will know all the machinery leading up to the Residue theorem).

Can anyone recommend such a resource?